# what is the particular solution of $y'' - y= -cos(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I solved it like this $r^2 - 1= 0 \Rightarrow r=1,-1$, so the roots are real, this means the complementary function will be of the form
$$y = A \exp(x)+ B \exp(-x).$$
Then, I tried to find the particular solution using variation of parameters method, I got particular solution $y=\frac{9}{4}\sin(x) -\frac{7}{4}\cos(x)$. Is this correct?

Comment: If you use undetermined coefficients instead you have $y_p=A\cos(x)+B\sin(x)$ and $y''-y=-2A\cos(x)-2B\sin(x)=-\cos(x)$ so $A=-1/2$ and $B=0$. I find variation of parameters is pretty much always less convenient for linear ODEs with constant coefficients than other methods. (Even when undetermined coefficients fails you, you can always use the operator factorization method, aka the annihilator method, given in @DanielWainfleet 's answer.)

Answer (score 3):

The nice thing about particular solutions is that, while you may need some method like variation of parameters to *find* them, they're dead easy to check. In this case, you just have to plug back into the original equation.

$$
y = \frac{9}{4}\sin(x) - \frac{7}{4} \cos(x)
$$
so
$$
y'' = -\frac{9}{4}\sin(x) + \frac{7}{4} \cos(x)
$$
and
$$
y'' - y = \frac{18}{4} \sin(x) + \frac{14}{4}\cos(x)
$$
is not a solution.

In this case, a particular solution that would work is $y = -\frac{1}{2}\cos(x)$.

Comment: Then, what will the general solution be?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think $\cos x$ is a particular solution ...

Comment: @Damien oops, missed a factor of -1/2! Fixed now, sorry.

Comment: @waheebahmed $y=A exp(x)+B exp(-x) - \frac{1}{2}\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. For any $g$ let $Ig=g$ and $I^2g=I(Ig)=g.$ And $Dg=g'$ and $D^2g=D(Dg)=g''.$ Then rather nicely we have $$y''-y= D^2y-I^2y=(D+I)(D-I)y=-\cos x.$$ Let $z=(D-I)y=y'-y.$ Then $z'+z=(D+I)z=(D+I)(D-I)y=-\cos x.$

So solve $z'+z=-\cos x.$ Then solve $y'-y=z.$